# Error installing jupyter notebook on windows 10

Tags: python, windows, jupyter-notebook

When I try to install Jupyter Notebook with,

```
pip3 install jupyter
```

I get the following,

> cywinpty.c
>       winpty/cywinpty.c(598): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'winpty.h': No such file or directory
>       error: command 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.15.26726\bin\HostX86\x86\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
>
> ---
>
> Command "c:\users\user\documents\python\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;**file**='C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-l1say6z1\pywinpty\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-178wq6f4\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-l1say6z1\pywinpty\

Python version 3.7.0
,
pip version 18.1

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem you should install activepython which is a distribution of ActiveState.

ActiveState provides you with a quick, easy and ready to use run-time environment for the language you want to code (in this case python).

To download the installer, visit the link https://www.activestate.com/products/activepython/downloads/, and select the OS you want, You'll be required to setup an account or login to download the files as it will set up all the dependencies on your machine specifically.

Once you're logged in, head over to the `Download Builds` tab and select the your OS and download the installer for your machine.
#
Once installation is complete, restart your your device and try installing `jupyter` again. It should install with no more issues

Good luck!!